# django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL: role "admin" does not exist

Tags: python, sql, база-данных, django, postgresql

Пытаюсь добавить postgresql в django. Создал пользователя и бд при makemigrations выдаёт ошибку. django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  role "admin" does not exist

Пользователь есть. Не понимаю в чем проблема.
Owner стоит. Слева на скрине видно, что он существует.

[image]

Ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -2):

Все пофиксилось, когда я просто создал новый сервер!